# How tortoise SVN do the Merge?Help Required

Tags: tortoisesvn

I am having a task of SVN Merge. But i am not sure hows SVN perform it.

Details:
we have Trunk & On Revision 99 we cut a branch called "code_2011".
Two different group of developer are working one on Trunk, another on branch.

Respective developer are committing their code.
Now both Trunk and branch has changed.

Now After code freeze we have Trunk on revision 200 and Branch on 299.
Now we want to merge the code on Trunk.

Both repositories are clean, now i right clicked on Trunk folder and clicked merge. but i am unable to understand the terminologies start-URl & Revision then End-URL & Revision. so that i can have final code from both repository on Trunk with all revision history stuff.

Could somebody Tell me how its done. & Is it different when i merge the from Trunk to Branch.

Thanks

Comment: What tool are you using to merge?

Comment: @Arpit: "How tortoise SVN do..." Also, see the tag.

Comment: Your terminology is so scrambled (are you sure you have two _repositories_?) it's hard to understand what you want to merge. Do you want to merge the branch back into the trunk? If so, do you want to keep the branch? Or do you want to merge fixes from either one into the other? Please clarify!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not logically different when you merge from branch to trunk or vice-verse.

Follow these steps for merging code from branch to trunk (Basic merging)-

1. Checkout the working copy of the trunk (Destination, where the merge is to be done).
2. Right Click on the **Trunk** and select **TortoiseSVN > Merge**
3. select the First option "**Merge a Range of revisions**"
4. Select the **Branch** URL to merge from.
5. For **Revision range to merge**, click on show log. It will show you the complete change log of the branch. Select all the revision that you want to merge (Ctrl+A) for all of them and select OK.
6. In the next dialog box, select Test Merge. It will show you the Test merge results, you can check if there are any conflicts or the merge is clean.
7. Finally, Merge.

This process will merge all the branch changes in your trunk's working copy (Local checkout). You need to commit the code after that.

Also, in case of conflicts, TortoiseSVN will automatically give you option to "Edit Conflicts" to resolve them using SVN Editor or leave them so they you can manually resolve them.

Hope this helps.

Cheers!

Comment: @sbi  i am sorry for the terminologies. We just cut a branch from the trunk , both got changed over time, now want to merge the changes in the Trunk, Does it matter whether i want the Branch later on or not?

Comment: @Techmaster: It whould not matter if you select "Merge a range of revisions" option while merging. Also, I would suggest you to keep the branch for future reference.

Comment: @Arpit i was trying using "Merge different Tree" option. because i guess its suitable for my requirement? Could put light on this option and from url& Revision, To Url & Revision, According to the revision nos i have given in my question.

Comment: Nope. Thats when you want to merge the difference of two branches into your working copy (Local checkout). This is certainly not your case, since you want to merge your branch changes back into the trunk

Comment: Actually, this might not be the best advice. If you want to reintegrate the branch into the trunk, you should do that.

Comment: Yes, that can be the option of you don't want to continue working on the branch anymore!

Comment: @Techmaster: (I didn't see your comment until I accidentally came by here again, because I hadn't posted to this answer, so your notification didn't reach me.) If you reintegrate, the branch will be unusable for further merging afterwards. (Which isn't bad, since everything is in the trunk then anyway, and you can just recreate a new one.)

Comment: @Arpit @Sbi, with arpit suggestion i am lossing the revisions history of branch after merge. I want history of both.

Comment: Yeah... @Techmaster, I am not sure if you got my point. If you follow the steps I've mentioned in the answer above, the changes of the branch will be migrated to trunk. History of trunk will be unaffected. Also, the branch and it's complete history will be intact. That's the best and the safest way to merge and keep both branch/trunk for future usage. Even if you continue developing in branch, you can again merge the changes later the same way.

Comment: @Arpit, my question is if i see the svn-log of the merged file, can i see the history of branch revision right there or not?

Comment: Nope. This is not possible with any of the ways to merge. The history of that filw will show the trunk's history and a new revision added to it for the merge operation

Comment: @Arpit It means Manual merge and SVN Merge are same thing, if i say i have only 5-6 files to merge. I am right

Comment: I'm afraid thats not true. Manual merge will be like a developer modifying the files and committing the code in the repo. While, SVN will still keep track that the code is merged from another branch. Logically, they won't have any difference.

Comment: @Arpit how does svn do the track. thats why my previous question was around the History of branch revision on merged files.

Comment: By track I meant that It would know about the merge when you will generate the reports and repository layout diagrams. If you don't want to take much pain, just manually merge the files (if you only have 5-6 of them). I don't understand why so much thought process is required

Answer (score 2):

Post the merge activity, you can also see the from-branch history in log.

There is an option at the bottom of show-log window: `stop on copy/rename`. Just deselect it, you will get to see all the affected revisions.